# QQuickImageProvider::requestImage image scaling, how to handle it

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qimage

I am trying to implement a simple PxImageProvider. The source image is static, and I am providing only one image.
It seems to be that requestedSize is always empty. Even when I try to modify the image size on the QML side, the image gets re-scaled, but it doesn't look like my PxImageProvider is doing the rescaling... is this normal?

What I have done is implement my PxImageProvider subclass so that when requestedSize is empty (either width or height null or negative), I provide the flipped original image (so I know I didn't do any rescaling).
But even when the QML side is trying to rescale the image, I always see my image flipped (rescaled, but flipped).

My .h header:

```
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickImageProvider>
#include <QImage>

class MyImageProvider :
    public QQuickImageProvider
{
public:
  MyImageProvider(QQmlApplicationEngine *engine, const QString &qmlId, const QImage *image = Q_NULLPTR);
  QImage requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize) override;
  void setImage(const QImage &image);

private:
  QImage _image;
};
```

and my .cpp:

```
#include "myimageprovider.h"

MyImageProvider::MyImageProvider(QQmlApplicationEngine *engine, const QString & qmlId, const QImage *image) :
  QQuickImageProvider(QQuickImageProvider::Image)
{
  if (image == Q_NULLPTR) {
    _image = QImage();
  }
  else {
    _image = *image;
  }
  engine->addImageProvider(qmlId, this);
}

QImage MyImageProvider::requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize)
{
  // Ignoring the id field, just one image to output
  *size = _image.size();
  if (requestedSize.isEmpty())
    return (_image.mirrored(true, true));
  else
    return (_image.scaled(requestedSize, Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
}

void MyImageProvider::setImage(const QImage &image)
{
  _image = image;
}
```

I create an instance, feeding it a 100x100 pixels image.
On the QML side:

```
    Rectangle {
      id: myImageBlock
      color: "grey"
      width: 250
      height: 250
      anchors.centerIn: parent

      Image {
        id: myImage
        source: "image://my_image/unusedId"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 50
        height: 50
      }
    }
```

I do get my image, rightly scaled to 50x50 over a 250x250 grey square... but the image is flipped, meaning the image wasn't scaled by my provider.
Is this how it is supposed to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html#requestImage):

> ### QImage QQuickImageProvider::requestImage(const QString &id, QSize
>   *size, const QSize &requestedSize)
>
> Implement this method to return the image with id. The default implementation returns an empty image.
>
> The id is the requested image source, with the "image:" scheme and
>   provider identifier removed. For example, if the image source was
>   "image://myprovider/icons/home", the given id would be "icons/home".
>
> **The requestedSize corresponds to the Image::sourceSize requested by an
>   Image item. If requestedSize is a valid size, the image returned
>   should be of that size.**
>
> In all cases, size must be set to the original size of the image. This
>   is used to set the width and height of the relevant Image if these
>   values have not been set explicitly.
>
> Note: this method may be called by multiple threads, so ensure the
>   implementation of this method is reentrant.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

You must use the [`sourceSize`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html#sourceSize-prop) of [`Image`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html).

```
Image {
    id: myImage
    source: "image://my_image/unusedId"
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    width: 50
    height: 50
    sourceSize.width: 50  // <---
    sourceSize.height: 50 // <---
}
```

Comment: I completely missed that property on the QML side. Now it all makes sense, thank you.